# joomla mvc tutorial editing component issue

Tags: joomla-3.x, component, mvc

I have gone through the steps provided here:

https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Developing_an_MVC_Component

I am currently on

https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Developing_an_MVC_Component/Adding_backend_actions

When I login to my administration portion of my joomla page and go to my component under components menu to access its default page. I get the normal fields you would see to make any changes. The tutorial adds 3 fields with JToolbarHelper::. These fields are new,edit,and delete. When I click any of the buttons to progress to another screen such as edit,add,or delete it brings me to an error page. complaining about the component not being found.The reason is a messed up link.

The link for the site now turns into

```
https://example.demojoomla.com/administrator/index.php?option=com_com_example&view=example&layout=edit
```

it should be

```
 https://example.demojoomla.com/administrator/index.php?option=com_example&view=example&layout=edit
```

Somewhere an extra com_ is being added and I have looked everywhere.
Does anyone understand why or where I should look to fix this issue?

within the form action for the admin page if i remove the com_ from that action it remove the com_com_ and reduce it to
    https://example.demojoomla.com/administrator/index.php?option=example&view=example&layout=edit

im starting to think that this is being caused by the controllers and or tasks but i cannot pin point the issue still

Comment: Have you done a full search of your code for the text "com_com"? A typo in the form action sounds a likely cause.

Comment: i have checked with windows explorer,my ftp clients, and i have looked at all the files that i think could have the mistake.

Comment: i added to the question as i noticed if the remove com_ from teh form action it will remove the extra com_ but still mess up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking further into it it seems i had miss named my controller classes for the legacy calls. Once I had fixed that it led me down a rabbit hole of renaming classes until it finally started working properly. 
The below code was not set proerply.

```
$controller = JControllerLegacy::getInstance
```

The hardest part of the MVC tutorial is that they use HelloWorld for everything and i must have gotten confused as to how it was working. In the next remake of my component i will use better classes that are more unique.